# Validate form wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I can not validate this form posting in wordpress, sending submit goes blank and shows no errors

**ad-post.php**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Publicar Post
*/
$wpdb->hide_errors(); 
nocache_headers();
global $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo(); // grabs the user info and puts into vars
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-process.php';
 get_header(); ?>
        <div id="page">
            <div class="categories">
                <h2 style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: none; background: url(<?php echo csp_images_url; ?>/sprite.png) left -738px repeat-x;text-align:center; padding-top: 5px; margin-top: 10px;">Categor&iacute;as</h2>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&orderby=name&exclude='.$category_id.''); ?>
                </ul>
                <?php get_sidebar('o'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="publish-form">
                <div class="post-form">
                    <h2>Envia tu Anuncio</h2>

                            <div class="box-yellow">
                                La publicaci&oacute;n de avisos es gratuito, sin embargo si usted desea destacar su anuncio o contratar publicidad en lugares estrat&eacute;gicos de la web, por favor <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="Contacte con Nosotros">p&oacute;ngase en contacto con nosotros</a>, estaremos
                                dispuestos a su disposici&oacute;n. 
                                <?php
                                $ok = classy_filter($_GET['ok']);
                                if ($err != "") { echo "<div id=\"err\" class=\"err\"><a id='closelink' href=\"#\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('err').style.display = 'none';\">X</a>$err</div>"; }

                                if ($ok == "ok") {
                                    echo "<div class=\"ok\"><strong>" . __('Muchas gracias!, su art&iacute;culo ha sido enviado satisfactoriamente.') . "</strong><br />";

                                if ( get_option("post_status") == "publish") { 
                                    echo __('Alguien revisar&aacute; su publicaci&ocute;n en breve. Si usted tiene alguna pregunta, p&oacute;ngase en contacto con el propietario del sitio.') . "<br />";
                                        }
                                    echo "</div>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>

                        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_post" name="new_post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
                            <?php wp_nonce_field('new-post'); ?>

                            <label for="title" class="post_tags"><?php _e('T&iacute;tulo de la Publicaci&oacute;n'); ?> <span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" id="title" class="mid" name="post_title" size="100" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $_POST['post_title'];?>" style="padding: 5px;" /><br /><br />

                            <label for="cat" class="post_tags">Por favor seleccione una categor&iacute;a <span>*</span>:</label>
                            <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Seleccione una Categoria&hide_empty=0&hierarchical=1&class=adfields&exclude='.$category_id.''); ?>
                            <br /><br />

                            <label for="post_tags">Suba una imagen<br /><br />
                            <small>(Las im&aacute;genes no deben ser mayores de 1MB, los formatos soportados son: jpg, png, gif y jpeg.)</small></label>
                            <input type="file" name="imgs[]" class="wwIconified" style="padding: 5px;" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <label for="description" class="post_tags"><?php _e('Escriba aqu&iacute; la descripci&oacute;n de su Aviso Clasificado'); ?> <span>*</span><br /><small>(Mientras mejor se explique, mejores resultados podr&aacute; obtener).</small></label><br />
                            <?php wp_editor(''. $_POST['content'].'', 'content', $settings ); ?>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <br />

                            <label for="post_tags" class="post_tags">Etiquetas <span>*</span> <small class="mini"><?php _e('(las etiquetas ayuda a mejorar la indexaci&oacute;n de su aviso, sep&aacute;relas con comas)'); ?></small></label>
                            <input type="text" id="post_tags" class="adfields" name="post_tags" size="60" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $_POST['post_tags']; ?>" style="padding: 5px;" />
                            <br /><br />

                            <label for="price" class="post_tags">Precio <span>*</span></label><br /><br />
                            <p><small>(Es necesario que inserte el monto con su respectivo s&iacute;mbolo; ejm. S/.10.00, $20.00 USD, etc.)</small></p>
                            <input type="text" id="price" class="adfields price" name="price" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <label for="post_tags" class="post_tags">Direcci&oacute;n/Ubicaci&oacute;n <span>*</span></label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="location" class="adfields location" name="location" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $_POST['location']; ?>" /><br />
                            <br />                        
                            <label for="post_tags" class="post_tags">Agregar URL <small><?php _e('(i.e. http://www.misitio.com)'); ?></small></label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="addURL" class="adfields url" name="addURL" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $_POST['addURL']; ?>" /><br />

                            <label for="post_tags" class="post_tags">Nombre de Contacto <span>*</span></label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="name" class="adfields name" name="name" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" /><br />

                            <label for="post_tags" class="post_tags">Tel&eacute;fono</label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="phone" class="adfields phone" name="phone" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>" /><br />

                            <label for="post_tags" class="post_tags">Correo Electr&oacute;nico <span>*</span></label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="email" class="adfields email" name="email" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /><br />

                            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Publicar el Aviso" class="submit_btn" /> 
                        </form>
                        <?php // } //if the form is ok don't display the form anymore ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**post-process.php**

this is the file that processes the validation and seems not to work

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'post') {

if ( get_option("permissions") == "no" ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){
        wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' );
        exit;
    };
}

    check_admin_referer( 'new-post' );
    $err = ""; $ok = "";
    $user_id        = $current_user->user_id;
    $post_title     = classy_filter($_POST['post_title']);
    $post_cat       = (int)classy_filter($_POST['cat']);
    $post_cat_array = array("$post_cat");

    if (isset ($_POST['content'])) { 
        $content = trim($_POST['content']); 
    } else { 
        echo 'Please enter the content'; 
    }

    //$title        = classy_filter($_POST['title']);
    $post_tags      = classy_filter($_POST['post_tags']);
    $addURL         = classy_filter($_POST['addURL']);
    $location       = classy_filter($_POST['location']);
    $price          = classy_filter($_POST['price']);
    $name           = classy_filter($_POST['name']);
    $phone          = classy_filter($_POST['phone']);
    $email          = classy_filter($_POST['email']);

    $imgs = strip_tags($_POST['imgs']);

    if ( $post_cat == "-1") {
        $err .= __('Por favor seleccione una categor&iacute;a') . "<br />";
    } else {
        global $wpdb;
        $cat_ids = (array) $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `term_id` FROM $wpdb->terms");
        if ( !in_array($post_cat, $cat_ids) && $post_cat != "-1") {
            $err .= __('La categor&iacute;a Seleccionada no Existe') . "<br />";
        }
    }

    if ($post_title == "" || $post_cat == "" || $post_tags == "" || $price == "" || $location == "" || $name == "") {
        $err .= __('Por favor llene los campos marcados como obligatorios *') . "<br />";
    }

    if ( !check_email($email) ) {
        $err .= __('Por favor ingrese un Correo Electr&oacute;nico V&aacute;lido') . "<br />";
    }

    if ( $total != $nr1nr2 ) {
        $err .= __('Los datos ingresados en el captcha son incorrectos') . "<br />";
    }

    if ( $err == "" ) {


//imgs
   //1024 bytes = 1kb
   //1024000 bytes = 1mb
   $image_folder_name = "imgs";
   $size_bytes = 1024000;
   $size_mb = $size_bytes / 1024000;
   $limitedext = array(".gif",".png",".jpg",".jpeg",".bmp");

        // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir
        $upload_arr = wp_upload_dir();
        $dir_to_make = trailingslashit($upload_arr['basedir']) . $image_folder_name;
        // $dir_to_make = "wp-content/uploads/imgs";
        $image_baseurl = trailingslashit($upload_arr['baseurl']) . $image_folder_name;
        $image_name = substr(sanitize_title(alphanumericAndSpace($post_title)), 0, 20);

        $i = rand();
        $imgs = "";
        $err2 = "";

        while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['imgs']['name'])) {
            if(!empty($value)) {
                $filename = strtolower($value);
                $filename = str_replace(" ", "-", $filename);
                //get image extension
                $tipul = strrchr($filename,'.');
                $filename = $image_name."-$i".$tipul;
                $add = "$dir_to_make/$filename";
                $image = "$image_baseurl/$filename";
                //$add = "$filename";

           //Make sure that file size is correct
                $file_size = $_FILES['imgs']['size'][$key]; //getting the right size that coresponds with the image uploaded
                if ($file_size == "0"){
                    $err2 .= __('El archivo $value tiene 0 bytes.') . "<br />";
                } else {
                    if ($file_size > $size_bytes){
                        $err2 .= __('El archivo $value es mayor de 5MB.') . "<br />";
                    }
                }
                //check file extension
                $ext = strrchr($filename,'.');
                if ( (!in_array(strtolower($ext),$limitedext)) ) {
                    $err2 .= __('El archivo $value no es una imagen v&aacute;lida.') . "<br />";
                }


                //echo $_FILES['archive']['type'][$key];
                if ( $err2 == "" ) {
                    if (!file_exists($dir_to_make)) { mkdir($dir_to_make, 0777); }
                    copy($_FILES['imgs']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
                    chmod("$add",0777);

                    //$imgs .= get_option('home')."/".$add.",";
                    $imgs .= $image . ",";

                }
                $err2 = "";
                $i++;
            }//if empty $value
        }//end while

        $post_code = time();
        $post_status = "publish";   

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title'    => $post_title,
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'post_category' => $post_cat_array,
            'post_status'   => $post_status,
            'tags_input'    => $post_tags
        ) );
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'imgs', $imgs, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'addURL', $addURL, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'location', $location, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'price', $price, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'name', $name, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', $phone, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'email', $email, true);

        $ok = "ok";

            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' );
        }
        exit;
    }

?>
```

help please

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_post" name="new_post">
```

to:

```
<form action="post-process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_post" name="new_post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ;  in your first lines

```
set_time_limit(0);
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'post') {

if ( get_option("permissions") == "no" ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){
        wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' );
        exit;
    };   <----------------------------Get rid of this SemiColon
}
```

http://phpcodechecker.com/ checks out your code with no errors even with the ;
But I'd go for that first.